# Relation between $V = RI$ and Ohm's law

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

According to the book Halliday et al., the equation$V = RI$ is not the Ohm's law but simply the resistance definition; the book states this definition applies to all kinds of conductors, ohmic or not.
But here is the question: if the equation $V = RI$ is a linear straight line passing from the origin of x and y axes, how can this relation be applied to non ohmic conductors in which the tension is not proportional to the current?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how the current varies with the applied potential, i.e. $I(V)$, then you can easily determine the resistance of the element as a function of applied voltage

$$R(V)=\frac{V}{I(V)}$$

For ohmic devices, $R(V)$ is a constant function.

Therefore for your second point, yes, if you were to plot $V(I)=RI$ then you would get a straight line for constant $R$, but it does not have to be true that $R$ is constant.